# parse data from txt which has one line

Tags: python

I've a text file which contains text as:

```
[-0.602849, 1.57312, -0.157513][-0.508125, 1.57352, -0.142647][-0.434815, 1.54734, -0.108053][-0.401875, 1.61105, -0.0748559]
```

each '[ ]' indicates a vertex position, and all the data in one line, I want to get the vertex position as a numpy array.

one solution is read all the data as a long string and then use ']' to split the string, and then use '[' to split, then use ',' to split, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `re.findall` and `numpy.fromstring` and `numpy.vstack`:

```
import numpy as np
import re

a = "[-0.602849, 1.57312, -0.157513][-0.508125, 1.57352, -0.142647][-0.434815, 1.54734, -0.108053][-0.401875, 1.61105, -0.0748559]"
arr = np.vstack([np.fromstring(i, sep=', ') for i in re.findall('\[(.+?)\]', a)])
arr
```

Output:

```
array([[-0.602849 ,  1.57312  , -0.157513 ],
       [-0.508125 ,  1.57352  , -0.142647 ],
       [-0.434815 ,  1.54734  , -0.108053 ],
       [-0.401875 ,  1.61105  , -0.0748559]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that matches from `[` to `]` to split it up. Then call `ast.literal_eval()` to parse each of the lists.

```
import re
import ast

line = '[-0.602849, 1.57312, -0.157513][-0.508125, 1.57352, -0.142647][-0.434815, 1.54734, -0.108053][-0.401875, 1.61105, -0.0748559]'
list_of_positions = map(ast.literal_eval, re.findall(r'\[[^]]*\]', line))
```